# how to apply filter in angular js which is not visible?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to apply filter in list view .Whenever I typed anything in input field it filter my list .I am able to filter when I write **username** which is visible to user .example when I write **"pa"** it sort my list and display only one row .that is correct.but when I write on **"keyword filter"** which is not visible to user it doesn't filter .In other words when I type **"Angular js"** on second input field ("keyword filter") ..It should display **pab**..Because **"pab"** have **Angular js** keyword .

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/TccgJydcZNkXQGpnbbP0?p=preview

```
// Code goes here

angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

  $scope.users = [

    {firstname: 'john', lastname: 'smith',

                keywords: ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "jQuery", "Photoshop"]

    },
    {firstname: 'pab', lastname: 'due',
             keywords: ["Ruby on Rails", "PostgreSQL", "AngularJS", "Node.js"]

    },
    {firstname: 'bob', lastname: 'rand',            keywords: ["java", "php", "test", "jira"]
}

  ];

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `ng-repeat` you are not filtering after your keyword input - you missed it. Just include it as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:userSearch | filter:{ keywords: keyword }">
```

Comment: please provide plunker

Comment: trying wait I am trying

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add the the same ng-model on the second input :

```
ng-model="userSearch"

<body ng-controller='myCtrl'>
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="username search" ng-model="userSearch">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="keyword search" ng-model="userSearch">
    </div>
  </div>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nqp45xwrZqPLIWDtjGvQ?p=preview

hope helps good luck.

Comment: The issue would be that this does not solely filter on the keywords and you wouldn't be able to filter for a different keyword and username at the same time

Comment: yes, since it is the same bind you cant filter two different words simultaneously. 
your solution solves better the problem.